# Any difference between explicit and implicit return in javascript function?

Tags: javascript, function, return

Is there any difference when I explicitly return from a function vs. implicitly return?

Here's the code that puzzles me ATM:

```
function ReturnConstructor(arg){
    // Private variable. 
    var privateVar = "can't touch this, return ctor.";

    // This is what is being exposed to the outside as the return object
    return {
        print: function() {
            console.log("ReturnConstructor: arg was: %s", arg);
        }
    };
}

function NormalConstructor(arg){
    // Private variable. 
    var privateVar = "can't touch this, normal ctor";

    // This is what is being exposed to the outside as "public"
    this.print = function() {
            console.log("NormalConstructor: arg was: %s", arg);
        };
}

var ret = new ReturnConstructor("calling return");
var nor = new NormalConstructor("calling normal");
```

Both objects ('ret' & 'nor') seem the same to me, and I'm wondering if it's only personal preference of whomever wrote whichever article I've read so far, or if there's any hidden traps there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use `new`, there's an implicit value. When you *don't* use `new`, there isn't.

When a function called with `new` returns an object, then that's the value of the `new` expression. When it returns something else, that return value is ignored and the object implicitly constructed is the value of the expression.

So, **yes**, there can be a difference.

Comment: So, by using the `var v = new ...` in my question, they are the same. The difference would come into play when I do something like: `ReturnConstructor("hello").print()` which is valid and will print: `ReturnConstructor: arg was: hello`, because it returns an object, that has `print` defined,as opposed to `NormalConstructor("hello")`, which returns `undefined`, and will throw an error if I try to use the "print()" method on the undefined object. (I'm still not sure who will use it that way though ... any examples?)

Comment: Right - the `new` operator makes a big difference in the semantics of a function call. Without `new`, an ordinary function call to a function with no explicit return value results in `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Implicit return only happens for single statement arrow functions, except When arrow function is declared with {}, even if it’s a single statement, implicit return does not happen:
[link](https://strongloop.com/strongblog/an-introduction-to-javascript-es6-arrow-functions/)

Comment: That's inexact, implicit return is available since ever via `new` keyword; check [Pointy's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21033556/any-difference-between-explicit-and-implicit-return-in-javascript-function#comment31620521_21033575).